# Como pegar o valor de uma variável que está apontando para uma lista

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Olá,

Preciso de uma ajuda neste código. Penso que seja relativamente simples para quem já tem  mais experiência.

Estou tentando pegar o valor de uma variável, mas ao debugar, vejo o endereço e não o valor.

```
// Meu xhtml em que o valor que preciso está no atributo conta da Lista (listaContasSelecionadas) que é uma lista que o usuário seleciona por meio de check box na tela.

<p:outputLabel for="contaCorrente">
    <b>Conta Corrente:</b>
</p:outputLabel>
<p:selectOneMenu id="contaCorrente"
    value="#{meuBean.contaCorrente}"
    valueChangeListener="#{meuBean.contaMudaLista}">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{ msg['selecione.um'] }" />
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{meuBean.listaContasSelecionadas}"
        var="dadosConta"
        itemLabel="#{dadosConta.conta}"
        itemValue="#{dadosConta}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>

// Meu Bean
// Declaraçao da lista 

private List<ContaDTO> listaContasSelecionadas;

`insira o código aqui`// Declaração da variável conta Corrente

@Getter @Setter
private String contaCorrente;

// Atribuição para pegar o dado da variável conta Corrente.

FormaPagto.setConta(getContaCorrente());

// Imprime o valor para conferência

System.out.println("conta "+getContaCorrente()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, creio que não seja necessário utilizar o evento `valueChangeListener="#meuBean.contaMudaLista}"`, pois no momento em que o valor for selecionado, automaticamente será atribuído para `private String contaCorrente`. Porém, esse atributo está no tipo `String`, logo, sua lista deveria ser `List<String> listaContasSelecionadas` e não `List<ContaDTO> listaContasSelecionadas`.

Tente alterar o atributo `private String contaCorrente` para `private ContaDTO contaCorrente`. Acrecente uma biblioteca de utilitários JSF: [*OmniFaces*](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/converters/SelectItemsConverter), utilizando um Conversor: `converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter"`, assim irá mostrar o valor e não o endereço.

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="contaCorrente"
    value="#{meuBean.contaCorrente}"
    converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItem itemLabel="#{ msg['selecione.um'] }" noSelectionOption="true" />
    <f:selectItems
        value="#{meuBean.listaContasSelecionadas}"
        var="dadosConta"
        itemLabel="#{dadosConta.conta}"
        itemValue="#{dadosConta}" />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```